# Mysql select query using NOT IN / LIKE to retrieve the data

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch the data in mysql using select query as below

```
Select tid from abc where abc.parameter not like '%DONE%'
```

But data return where parameter column have %DONE% VALUE.

Here I am giving sample data for better understanding

```
tid    parameter    value
***************************
1       abc         123
1       def         456
1       ghi         789
```

I need to retrieve tid where def not in .

Comment: I do not see any done anywhere.

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand - you are trying to select the `tid`s that don't have a `def` parameter in any row, right?

Comment: Yes @Mureinik You are right bro

Comment: If you have got solution then fine else provide some sample data which matched with your query as you are searching not like '%DONE%' but in your sample data there is no any value like 'DONE'.

Comment: Check the encoding of server if it uses case sensitive match!? try this `abc.parameter COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci not like '%DONE%'` this might help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Schema

```
create table abc
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    tid int not null,
    parameter varchar(20) not null,
    value int not null
);

insert abc(tid,parameter,value) values (1,'abc',123),(1,'def',456),(1,'ghi',789);
```

### Queries

```
select id,tid from abc where abc.parameter not like '%DONE%';
+----+-----+
| id | tid |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   1 |
|  2 |   1 |
|  3 |   1 |
+----+-----+

select id,tid from abc where abc.parameter not like '%abc%';
+----+-----+
| id | tid |
+----+-----+
|  2 |   1 |
|  3 |   1 |
+----+-----+
```

Looks as expected to me.

Note, NOT IN is dangerous in the case of NULLs. One must know there data well, else use NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 0):

Your tid is same, the returned data might be right, but due to ambiguity in your tid you feel that you are getting wrong result.

Comment: some of the tid which doesn't def string, I want to retrieve those tid's.

Comment: select id,tid from abc where abc.parameter not like '%three%';
    +----+-----+ +----+-----+
    | id | tid |parameter
    +----+-----++----+-----+
    |  1 |   1 |one
    |  2 |   1 |two
    |  3 |   1 |three
    |  4 |   2 |one
    |  5 |   2 | two
     +----+-----+
     It should retrieve the value id 5